# react native get response from then and assign to variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get thumbnail path and storing to a variable to be used, But I am getting **undefined**

```
getThumbnail(filePath){
  let thumbnailURL = RNThumbnail.get(filePath)
    .then((response) => response.path)
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.warn(responseData);
      return responseData;
    }).catch(error => console.warn(error));
  alert(thumbnailURL);
  //return thumbnailURL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.then` doesn't work like that, it won't return a value. You could do:

```
  let thumbnailURL;

  RNThumbnail.get(filePath)
    .then((response) => response.path)
    .then((responseData) => {
      thumbnailURL = responseData;
      alert(thumbnailURL);
    }).catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

but you have to continue computation inside the second `then` call because the value is only going to be reliable there

You're better off using `async/await`, just refactor your code to this:

```
async function getThumbnail(filePath){
  try {
    let thumbnailURL = await RNThumbnail.get(filePath)
    alert(thumbnailURL)
  } catch(err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
```

read more about [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: tried 1st answer getting same undefined error, 2nd answer throwing error

Comment: well it's a little weird for you to resolve it twice, what is the purpose of your second `.then` call? I changed the second example, try that

Comment: i don't want second then, if i can get it with single then, that's ok for me

Comment: any other way @Robbie

Comment: async await is the way, did you see my udpated example?

Answer (score 0):

For React app, most likely you will want to set the response as state:

```
state = {
  thumbnailURL: ''
}

getThumbnail = (filePath) => {
  RNThumbnail.get(filePath)
  .then(response => response.path)
  .then(responseData => {
      this.setState({
        thumbnailURL: responseData
      })
    })
  .catch(error => console.warn(error))
}

render() {
  return (
    <img src={this.state.thumbnailURL} />
  )
}
```

You will need arrow function on `getThumbnail` for lexical binding so that you can access `this.setState()`.

---

*Edit:*

You can't actually make `getThumbnail()` return `thumbnailURL` value right away. `getThumbnail()` can however return the promise, and you resolve it at the place where you want access to `thumbnailURL`:

```
getThumbnail = filePath => {
  return RNThumbnail.get(filePath)
    .then(response => response.path)
    .then(responseData => responseData)
    .catch(error => console.warn(error))
}

IWannaAccessThumbnailURLHere = () => {
  this.getThumbnail('....')
  .then(thumbnailURL => {
    // do things with thumbnailURL
  })
}
```

Or, use `setState`, re-render then you can access `this.state.thumbnailURL` in the next render-cycle.

Comment: I don't want to store it in the state, instead i want to return it in a function

Comment: it's actually not possible to make `getThumbnail()` returns the value right away. Check my updated answer for other possibility.

Comment: actually i want to loop in render to get a path of the stored video file, so this won't work, any other solution for my actual requirement?